# Implementing a endless scroll with Rails 3 and Jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implementing an endless scroll on my project. I'm using a mix of the Railscast [#114 Endless Page](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page) and [this](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To:-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery).

Everything works fine besides a weird behavior when I try to stop sending requests when the page hits its end.

So far I have:

Controller:

```
def show
    @title = Photoset.find(params[:id]).name
    @photos = Photoset.find(params[:id]).photo.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
end
```

Show.html.erb:

```
<% content_for :body_class, '' %>
<%= render 'shared/header' %>
<div id="photos_container">
    <div id="photos_header">
    <h2><%= @title %></h2>
    </div>
    <%= render :partial => 'photo', :collection => @photos %>
</div>
<%= render :partial => 'endless_scroll' %>
```

Javascript (loaded via partial):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var page = 1,
  loading = false,
  finish = false;

  function nearBottomOfPage() {
    return $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200;
  }

  function finish() {
    finish = true;
  }

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if (loading) {
      return;
    }

    if(nearBottomOfPage() && !finish) {
      loading=true;
      page++;
      $.ajax({
        url: '/photosets/<%= params[:id] %>?page=' + page,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function() {
          loading=false;
        }
      });
    }
  });
}());
</script>
```

show.js.erb

```
$("#photos_container").append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'photo', :collection => @photos) %>");
<% if @photos.total_pages == params[:page].to_i() %>
    page.call 'finish'
<% end %>
```

As you can see, on my `show.js.erb` I have a `page.call` that assigns true to the `finish` variable. This stops the requests.

The wired thing is that it never loads the last page. When `@photos.total_pages == params[:page].to_i()` instead of just calling the `finish` function and setting the variable to `true`, it's also preventing the `$("#photos_container").append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'photo', :collection => @photos) %>");` from running.

It sends the request to the controller, runs the SQL but doesn't append the last page.

If I change the condition to `@photos.total_pages < params[:page].to_i()` it works, but send an extra request to a page that doesn't exist.

I'd appreciate any help on my implementation. I'm not sure if there's a more adequate (Rails) way to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't know Rails but generally isn't params[:page].to_i() a zero-based index? so if params[:page].to_i() is for example 5, then photos.total_pages would be 6 (pages 0-5).

Comment: Have you inspected the `@photos` variable on the last page? I think it's not appending anything because the collection is empty on the last page. The `finish` variable is not used by any code you pasted too, but I don't think that's related.

Comment: In your ajax call you have success method where you only set the loading to false. Where does the response go? If it is not injected into the DOM then variable won't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can render html from the partial when request is xhr type:

```
def show
  photoset = Photoset.includes(:photos).find(params[:id])
  @title = photoset.name
  @photos = photoset.photo.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  if request.xhr?
    render '_photo', :layout => false
  end
end
```

Then use ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/photosets/<%= params[:id] %>?page=' + page,
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'script',
  success: function(response) {
    $("#photos_container").append(response);
    if (response == "") {
      //stop calling endless scroll
    }
  });  
});
```